# c# Build very large text file from SQL query

Tags: c#, sql

I am taking 100+ tables from a SQL Database and writing all the data into 1 file.  In SQL, I ran a complex query to format the tables into one view. 
In VS, I am connecting to SQL and selecting * from the view and using String Builder to build the file.

This works if I only grab 5% of the data and crashes with a memory exception if i try to grab 100%.  The view has 10 million+ records.  I am looking for advice.  Thanks.

```
string cs4 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["example"].ConnectionString;
StringBuilder sb4 = new StringBuilder();
using (SqlConnection con4 = new SqlConnection(cs4))
{
    string strTQuery = @"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[view]";
    SqlDataAdapter da4 = new SqlDataAdapter(strTQuery, con4);
    DataSet ds4 = new DataSet();
    da4.Fill(ds4);

    ds4.Tables[0].TableName = "Example";

    foreach (DataRow exDR in ds4.Tables["Example"].Rows)
    {
        sb4.Append(exDR["A"].ToString() + strDelimiter);
        sb4.Append(exDR["B"].ToString() + strDelimiter);
        sb4.Append(exDR["C"].ToString() + strDelimiter);
        sb4.Append(exDR["D"].ToString());
        sb4.Append("\r\n");
    }
}

StreamWriter file4 = new StreamWriter(@"\\Desktop" + todaysDate + ".csv");
file4.WriteLine(sb4.ToString());
file4.Close();
```

Comment: Write to the file as you read from the result - you're trying to shove all of that data into a string in memory, only writing to a file at the end.  I'm guessing you have far less memory than you have data.

Comment: @DStanley - won't the DataSet also hold all the data as well?  Jay - Perhaps using a `SqlDataReader` and doing as DStanley said and writing to the file as you read would work better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned by `D Stanley` you need to write at the same time you are reading so everything goes right to disk and does not go to memory first and then disk. Something like this would work.

```
string cs4 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["example"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection con4 = new SqlConnection(cs4))
using(StreamWriter file4 = new StreamWriter(@"\\Desktop" + todaysDate + ".csv"))
{
    string strTQuery = @"SELECT A, B, C, D FROM [dbo].[view]";
    var command = new SqlCommand(strTQuery, con4);
    con4.Open();
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while(reader.Read())
    {
        file4.Write(reader.GetString(0) + strDelimiter);
        file4.Write(reader.GetString(1) + strDelimiter);
        file4.Write(reader.GetString(2) + strDelimiter);
        file4.Write(reader.GetString(3));
        file4.Write("\r\n");
    }
}
```

You should also use a SqlDataReader instead of a DataSet as this is a forward moving pointer and retrieves results with each iteration.

Comment: Thank you! SqlDataReader was the fix for me.  Very much appreciated to all who commented.

Comment: @Jay - glad it helped. Once you feel you have found an answer among the answers posted please mark it as such using the check mark next to the answer. You can only mark a single posted answer as the answer for your question. Once you get enough rep (+15) you can also upvote answers and that is not restricted to just one answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to store the whole file in the runtime memory, that's why you're getting the memory error. Try saving the chunks of file instead and ammending the file.

try

```
string cs4 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["example"].ConnectionString;
            StringBuilder sb4 = new StringBuilder();
            using (SqlConnection con4 = new SqlConnection(cs4))
            {
                StreamWriter file4 = new StreamWriter(@"\\Desktop" + todaysDate + ".csv", true);
                string strTQuery = @"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[view]";
                SqlDataAdapter da4 = new SqlDataAdapter(strTQuery, con4);
                DataSet ds4 = new DataSet();
                da4.Fill(ds4);

                ds4.Tables[0].TableName = "Example";

                foreach (DataRow exDR in ds4.Tables["Example"].Rows)
                {
                    sb4 = new StringBuilder();
                    sb4.Append(exDR["A"].ToString() + strDelimiter);
                    sb4.Append(exDR["B"].ToString() + strDelimiter);
                    sb4.Append(exDR["C"].ToString() + strDelimiter);
                    sb4.Append(exDR["D"].ToString());
                    sb4.Append("\r\n");

                    file4.WriteLine(sb4.ToString());
                }
                file4.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the `DataSet` will try to store all the data as well so the memory issue will not be resolved while using one.  Using a `SqlDataReader` would be a better choice.  Also, creating a new `StringBuilder` each time through the loop doesn't seem like the best choice.  It might be better to clear the contents of the existing one.

Comment: Yeah u right. But the problem itself is that he tries to store all data in the runtime memory.

Comment: My point is that just changing to a StreamWriter will not fix the problem.  Using a DataSet will also hold all data in memory as well.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in this line:

```
file4.WriteLine(sb4.ToString());
```

The reason is no object in CLR can be greater than 2GB.
Your string in this case is exceptionaly big and such behavior is not even needed (ToString I mean).
To avoid this problem use FileStream to write your data as you receive it.